# How to initialize / run a prototype class by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

i have this block of prototype code

```
Product.ConfigurableSwatches = Class.create();
Product.ConfigurableSwatches.prototype = {
    productConfig: false,
    configurableAttributes: {},
    initialize: function(productConfig, config) {....},
    setConfig: function(x){}, ..
}
```

This block of code isn't running/working for the out of DOM(Document object model) elements i.e for the elements that is added later on the DOM. ?

So, my question how to make it work with javascript/jquery call ? Because from jquery i can make it work for out of DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to call a specific function  of this class it can be done as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Product.ConfigurableSwatches.initialize(arguments); 
</script>
```

Hope this helps!!